# Function in function cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to load PHP file with random image to `<div>` every 2 seconds with fade effect so i use javascript and jQuery. I write function to hide div, load file in, than show it and wait 2 seconds, then it should call function again, but it happend just once then it stop.

Here is the function:

```
function random(){
   $("#randomImage1").animate({opacity: '0.0'}).load("../images/randomImage.php").animate({opacity: '1.0'}).delay(2000, function(){
   random();
});
random();
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
(function random(){
  var timer;
  $("#randomImage1").animate({opacity: '0.0'}).load("../images/randomImage.php", function(){
     $(this).animate({opacity: '1'});
     timer = setTimeout(random, 2000);
  });
})();
```

Here we create self-invoking function and call it inside `setTimeout` so that it gets called again and again AFTER your image loading and animation part is complete. You would need to call `clearTimeout(timer)` to stop running `setTimeout` once all your images are loaded.

Comment: Saying "Do this" and posting code is meaningless. -1 until you explain **why**.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Go ahead and do -1, I would comment like `It would be better to explain +1 though` if I had seen your answer.

Comment: Upvoting would give the wrong impression - that I think the answer is useful. Without explaining what was wrong about the original approach the person asking the question doesn't learn anything; they just get code that works.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Can't argue with, just do whatever you feel is best

Answer (score 1):

try adding `setTimeout(random, 2000);` after the `load` request is completed:

```
function random(){
  var rndImg = $("#randomImage1");
  rndImg.fadeOut().load("../images/randomImage.php",function(){
      rndImg.fadeIn();
      setTimeout(random, 2000);
  });
};
random()
```

Comment: +1 for correctly fading in the image in the callback for `.load()`

Answer (score -3):

The problem you have is that you're trying to use `.delay()` as a replacement for the native `setTimeout()`, which isn't what it's intended to do. The `.delay()` function is designed to add a pause between jQuery animation effects, not to delay the execution of another function, and doesn't accept a callback function. See the jQuery documentation for the [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function.

As has already been covered in previous answers, you can use the native `setInterval()` function to implement the delay you're after:

```
function random(){
    $("#randomImage1").animate({opacity: '0.0'}).load("../images/randomImage.php").animate({opacity: '1.0'});
    setInterval(random, 2000);
}
random();
```

Note that this will animate the `#randomImage1` element back to full opacity, and set the interval to call the function again, even if the AJAX call from `.load()` didn't return a success response. If that's not what you want, you can instead move that code into an anonymous function passed as the success callback on `.load()`, like so:

```
function random(){
    $("#randomImage1").animate({opacity: '0.0'}).load("../images/randomImage.php", 
    function() {
        $("#randomImage1").animate({opacity: '1.0'});
        setInterval(random, 2000) 
    });
}
random();
```

Comment: I hope you do not get further down votes for your duplicate answer (posted after more than 30 minutes)

Comment: @Blaster I really don't mind if I do, I think the loss of rep is worthwhile to attempt to change the culture that posting code alone is enough.

Comment: I agree with you but there should be culture of some patience as well so that others could get a chance to explain their answer further. You almost always see edits for answers, it is hard to be perfect in first attempt. You add more details, examples, doc links, etc in your subsequent edits. This would bring you to conclusion of just a comment not a down vote like I explained in my first comment to your first comment in my answer.

Comment: @Blaster This happens **all the time**, though. Answers that consist only of (admittedly correct) code are upvoted extensively, because they're considerably faster to write and post, and a lot of people seem to equate "posted fastest" with "wrote the best answer". The result of that is that more in-depth answers, that provide information about what the asker was originally doing wrong, why that isn't the correct way to do it, etc are pushed further down the page, and not necessarily seen.

Comment: In my opinion, best answers get more up votes ("sometimes" it is not so), this is community of professional and "mature" people after all